# Loop to populate blank fields

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access

I have VBA code in MS Access, triggered by a button, that will populate blank fields.

I want to know how I can repeat the action until all blank fields are populated.

How does looping work?

```
If Me.Team = "GSAP Accounts" Then
    If Me.Mantainer_Status = "Completed" Then
        
        If IsNull(Me.Line_Items) Then
            If Me.Line_Item_Passed_After_Validation < Me.Total_Line_Items_Raised Then
                Me.Line_Items = Me.Total_Line_Items_Raised.Value
            Else
                Me.Line_Items = Me.Line_Item_Passed_After_Validation.Value
                Forms!KPIREFRESH.Requery
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: For Each ctl In frm.Controls [next line>]   If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox  Then do_your_thing  Endif  Next ctl

Comment: There are many tutorials on this topic. What exactly do you not understand about loop structures?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function FillNullFields()

Dim FormControls as Control 'Can be any Var name you want

'This will Loop Through EVERY control including Buttons / labels / and such
'So it's important to check the Control Type.
For Each FormControls in Me.Controls 

'In here you can Specify the control types you want checked
Select Case FormControls.ControlType 

   Case is = acTextBox 
     If isnull(FormControls) then 
       Formcontrols = "[Your Values here]"
     End If
'You can grab everything that the control has even if it's not listed after the [.]
'VBA just won't show it to you since it still doesn't know what the Control Actually 
'have.
'Example
'FormControls.Enabled = True 'This won't show up in the Editor but it would run it

End Select

Next FormControls

End Sub
```

Basically For Loops is used to cycle a Finite amount of times so you can use an integer to specify it , in this case , we are asking VBA to Cycle through All available controls in the Form.